# In SSH, is a keystroke shown as soon as the client presses a key?

Tags: ssh

SSH client sends all keystrokes to the server and the server echoes them back.

Does a terminal emulation software like PuTTY show the keystroke after the echo is received from server or as soon as the client pushes a key? I just want to know if I am correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say the text is displayed after the server echos it back to the terminal for the following reason -

When you login to a server, you type your username and password. The text of your username will appear, but not the password. The same applies when entering passwords for other services, such as mysql.

So it seems it is the server(or app on server) that decides what is displayed.

You can also download the source code for openssh and have a look :)

Comment: I think here is only relevant what you said about the other services, because I suppose the SSH password is asked for by the client.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the client. As per your specific question about PuTTY, it has a option to turn local echo on or off.

[image]